# Из list в Search

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день. Делаю сайт с помощью Bootstrap 3.6 и прошу помочь сделать вертикальный список при уменьшении размера экрана (скажем для 768 и меньше) в строку поиска [image: Пример экрана большого размера]

и далее вместо того, что бы отображался список "New text link" в простую строку поиска.

[image: Пример жкрана для мобильной версии]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `@media` - при уменьшении до 768px у меню `display:none;` , а у search - `display:block/inline/inline-block`, и т.д.